# ESXi Stop Delay Shown as -1 in Configuration File

Tags: autostart, esxi

I'm trying to pull info about the autostart configuration on ESXi 7. Via the web interface the stop delay is configured to 60 seconds, but within the /etc/vmware/hostd/vmAutoStart.xml file the stop delay is shown as -1 on some of the systems. Does anyone know why this is? Attached are 2 images of the web interface and the configuration file for reference

[image: Web Configuration]

[image: Configuration file]